# Deriving the Exponential Decay Rate in Damped Oscillation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I am currently working on this book: https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/15-5-damped-oscillations

The position as a function of time for damped oscillations is given by $$x(t)=A_0e^{-\frac{bt}{2m}}\cos(\omega t+\phi).$$
It is basically the equation for SHM but also including an exponential decay rate and I would like to know how it is found.

Comment: Solve the differential equation $m \ddot{x} + b\dot{x} + kx =0$, which models damped simple harmonic motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figure 15.26 in your reference shows the exponential damping factor as the red dashed curve. If you take the natural logarithm of this curve you get a linear function, the slope of which gives you the decay rate $b/2m$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the damped SHO equation of motion:
$$\frac{\text{d}^2x}{\text{d}t^2} + \omega^2 x + \frac{b}{m} \frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = 0 \tag{1}$$
Defining the velocity $v = \text{d}x/\text{d}t$, we can write equation (1) as a system:
$$\begin{cases} \frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t} = - \omega^2 x - \frac{b}{m}v \\ \frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = v\end{cases} \tag{2}$$
Writing equation (2) in matrix notation,
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\begin{bmatrix}x \\v\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ - \omega^2 & - \frac{b}{m}\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}x \\v\end{bmatrix} \tag{3}$$
Where "$\cdot$" denotes the matrix product. We [want the eigenvalues and eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) of the matrix of coefficients on the right-hand side of equation (3), so we need to write down the *characteristic equation*:
$$\operatorname{det}\Big(\begin{bmatrix}- \lambda & 1 \\ - \omega^2 & -\frac{b}{m} - \lambda\end{bmatrix}\Big) = 0 \tag{4}$$
Evaluating the determinant, we get:
$$\lambda^2 + \frac{b}{m}\lambda + \omega^2 = 0 \tag{5}$$
Let's define $\gamma = b/2m$ for concision. Solving equation (5) for the eigenvalues,
$$\lambda_{\pm} = - \gamma \pm i \sqrt{\omega^2 - \gamma^2} \tag{6}$$
For the eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}_{\pm}$ of the matrix of coefficients, we can write the eigenvalue-eigenvector equations:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ - \omega^2 & - \frac{b}{m}\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{v}^*_{\pm} = \lambda_{\pm} \mathbf{v}^*_{\pm} \tag{7}$$
Solving equation (7), we find that eigenvectors are scalar multiples of the following vectors:
$$\mathbf{v}_{\pm} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ \lambda_{\pm}\end{bmatrix} \tag{8}$$
The general solution to equation (1) is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ v\end{bmatrix} = c_+ e^{\lambda_{+} t} \mathbf{v}_+ + c_{-} e^{\lambda_{-} t} \mathbf{v}_{-}\tag{9}$$
Now to find the coefficients $c_+$ and $c_{-}$, we need to choose some *initial data*:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x(t=0) \\ v(t=0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\tag{10}$$
Notice that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors obey this identity:
$$\frac{\lambda_- \mathbf{v}_+ - \lambda_+ \mathbf{v}_{-}}{\lambda_{-}-\lambda_{+}}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}\tag{11}$$
So we can write the initial data in terms of the eigenvectors:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x(0) \\ v(0)\end{bmatrix} = \frac{x_0}{\lambda_{-}-\lambda_{+}}\big(\lambda_{-}\mathbf{v}_{+}- \lambda_{+}\mathbf{v}_{-}\big) \tag{12}$$
Substituting $t=0$ into equation (9) and setting the result equal to equation (12), one finds:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ v\end{bmatrix} = \frac{x_0}{\lambda_{-}-\lambda_+} \big(\lambda_{-}e^{\lambda_+ t}\mathbf{v}_+ - \lambda_+ e^{\lambda_{-} t}\mathbf{v}_{-}\big) \tag{13}$$
We're only interested in the position function:
$$x(t) = \frac{x_0}{\lambda_{-} - \lambda_+}\big(\lambda_{-}e^{\lambda_+ t} - \lambda_{+} e^{\lambda_- t}\big) \tag{14}$$
Your equation is valid in the **underdamped regime**, where $\gamma^2 < \omega^2$. In this case, from equation (6) we see that the imaginary parts of the eigenvalues are nonzero. Substituting the eigenvalues into equation (14) and using Euler's formula, $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, one finds:
$$\boxed{x(t) = x_0 e^{-\gamma t}\Big[ \cos(\sqrt{\omega^2 - \gamma^2}t) + \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\omega^2 - \gamma^2}}\sin(\sqrt{\omega^2 - \gamma^2}t) \Big] }\tag{15}$$
To write equation (15) using a single $\cos$ function, one can use the *harmonic addition theorem*:
$$A \cos \theta + B \sin \theta = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \cos \big(\theta - \arctan(\frac{B}{A})\big)$$
So the coefficients in your function:
$$\begin{align}A_0 &= \omega \sqrt{\frac{2}{\omega^2 - \gamma^2}}\\ \phi &= \arctan(\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\omega^2 - \gamma^2}})\end{align}$$
Note that the $\omega$ in your function is $\sqrt{\omega^2 - \gamma^2}$ here.

Comment: that seems much to advanced, but know that I appreciate the time you put in and I will definitely come back to it when I have learned such mathematical concepts